# Reusing Java objects to avoid repetitive work?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Everytime, before sending a request to an HTTP server, I need to create a java bean and set the values of its members, then transform it to XML, since that server only accepts this data formatted as XML.  There are some common member values of this java bean, and I don't want to create a new instance for each request.

At first, I thought of the *Prototype* design pattern, but after reading "Effective java", I think it wouldn't work.

Any other suggestions?

Thank you, and there are some code to make it clear:

```
    /**  
 * @Title: SSOManager.java
 * @Prject: TIJDemo
 * @Package: com.common
 * @Description: TODO
 * @author: Administrator  
 * @date: 2014-1-4 上午7:58:32
 * @version: V1.0  
 */
package com.common;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * @author Administrator
 *
 */
public class SSOManager {

    private static String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/SSO/";

    public SSOEntity getUserNameById(SSOEntity entity) {
        return requestSSO(entity, "GetUserNameById");
    }

    public SSOEntity modifyUserName(SSOEntity entity) {
        return requestSSO(entity, "ModifyUserName");
    }

    public SSOEntity register(SSOEntity entity) {
        return requestSSO(entity, "Register");
    }

    private SSOEntity requestSSO(SSOEntity entity, String url) {

        String requestXml = getXmlFromEntity(entity);
        String requestUrl = serverUrl + url;
        String result = httpRequest(requestXml, requestUrl);
        return getEntityFromXml(result);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param entity
     * @return
     */
    private String getXmlFromEntity(SSOEntity entity) {
        String result = "";
        /**
         * generate xml from this entity, and sign data
         */
        return result;
    }

    private SSOEntity getEntityFromXml(String xml) {

        /**
         * transform xml to java bean
         */

        return null;
    }

    private String httpRequest(String xml, String url) {

        String result = "";
        /**
         * request another web server, get xml
         */
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // this property is for md5 sign, each server has a different key
        String applicationKey = "hellokitty";   

        SSOManager sm = new SSOManager();
        SSOEntity response = null;

        // one servlet, get user info, need an object of SSOEntity
        SSOEntity entity = new SSOEntity();
        entity.setApplicationKey(applicationKey);
        entity.setUserId("124");

        response = sm.getUserNameById(entity);

        // another servlet, modify user name, need an object of SSOEntity too
        entity.setApplicationKey(applicationKey);
        entity.setUserId("456");
        entity.setUserName("I want you");
        response = sm.modifyUserName(entity);

        // there are some many servlet for me with this creation ...
        /**
         * ...
         */
    }
}



 class SSOEntity implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String userName;
    private String userId;
    private String email;
    private String passwd;
    private String mobile;

    private String applicationKey;
    /**
     * @return the applicationKey
     */
    public String getApplicationKey() {
        return applicationKey;
    }
    /**
     * @param applicationKey the applicationKey to set
     */
    public void setApplicationKey(String applicationKey) {
        this.applicationKey = applicationKey;
    }
    /**
     * @return the userName
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    /**
     * @param userName the userName to set
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the userId
     */
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    /**
     * @param userId the userId to set
     */
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    /**
     * @return the passwd
     */
    public String getPasswd() {
        return passwd;
    }
    /**
     * @param passwd the passwd to set
     */
    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }
    /**
     * @return the mobile
     */
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    /**
     * @param mobile the mobile to set
     */
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

Comment: `FlyWeight` perhaps, if it has common values

Comment: I think it's worth to clarify why you want to avoid to create new objects

Comment: And add some code, all is pretty vague

Comment: I wouldn't waste time worrying about this unless you're getting a genuine performance issue. You can't do anything in Java without creating objects, that's just how it works. Unnecessary object creation can be wasteful but I wouldn't call a separate object for each request wasteful. In fact there's an argument for the request to be an immutable object here to stop request parameters inadvertently changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object that you are trying to create `SSOEntity` is an object of ***Request scope***, so it has to be created per request. For every new request that you need to send to the HTTP server is a totally different state which has to be stored in a new object to represent that state. Hence it is a one-to-one mapping.

You *don't have to worry* about creating new object per request as it is not at all a thing to worry unless you have huge load on your application.

I work on application that creates `Request` and `Response` objects per request and believe you me it does not matter. The only thing you have to worry about is heap memory allocation and garbage collection algorithms and you are good to go.

A reference of a credible source, even Apache tomcat does the same thing. So you have to create objects wherever necessary.

Also as the comment by @BenThurley suggests there are opinions about `Request` being immutable, which should also be followed according to me. It provides so much simplicity.

At last: *Creating objects is cheap, so don't worry about overhead*.

Comment: As the java garbage collection working, should I worry about memory allocation?

Comment: Yes you should worry about proper memory allocation if your application has to support high throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple oops concept. Use parent class to have common properties, and then the subclass will have changing properties. Try the **builder** pattern to build the subclass or every request as it says in **Effective Java.**

Answer (score 0):

For sure this is best done as Prototype.

Probably the reason that Effective Java left you thinking you should not is Bloch is very down on the failed clone implementation in Java. I talked to him about this once in person. He does a great job in the book of laying out exactly how it a. went wrong, and b. efforts to rehab it were foiled due to stupid politics at Sun.

The reality is, though, that you don't have to use the clone the SDK provides. As a matter of fact, clone is not necessarily the best way to do Prototype.

Any time you need to make objects with some common state already established, you are doing prototype. The whole DI world is Singletons and Prototype.

The other suggestion that you use Builder makes no sense UNLESS you are going to set certain values on the Builder once then keep using it to create new instances, e.g.:

```
A.Builder a = new A.Builder().x(blah).y(blah);

b = builder.z(blah).build();
c = builder.z(otherBlah).build();
```

The idea that you should merely subclass also makes no sense unless the common state is known at compile time.

Make your own clone or reuse Builder.

Comment: I think, there is nothing to do with Builder. Since mutil-thread will access the SSOEntity, Singletion may also helpless.